# managing different fonts path in bower-installer

Tags: css, fonts, bower

I'm using bower to get tierce party libraries into bower_components, then bower-installer to copy only the required files.

My install section of bower.json is the following:

```
"install": {
    "path": {
      "js": "app/bower/{name}/js",
      "css": "app/bower/{name}/css",
      "eot": "app/bower/{name}/fonts",
      "svg": "app/bower/{name}/fonts",
      "ttf": "app/bower/{name}/fonts",
      "woff": "app/bower/{name}/fonts"
    },
    "sources": {
      "font-awesome": [
        "bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Problem come when I try to use both font-awesome and weather-icons : the CSS file of the first library use a font path of `../fonts/*`, and the second one `../font/*` (without *s*). How can I manage those conflicting path ?

I tried :

- Modifying the CSS : it gets overwritten at each `bower installer`
- Create a symbolic link `font` to `fonts` : the link is lost if the target  directory is deleted to be recreated with bower-installer

Comment: I wonder why people still use font-awesome with http://www.fontello.com being freely available.

Comment: I think just because font-awesome is well known from fontello. I didn't knew it before. It seems interessing...